# Spaghetti Fund Raiser Lunch

Tags: spaghetti

How do I figure out how much spaghetti, sauce, etc that need for a fund raising lunch that is targeting 100 to 125 people...we want to be generous in our portions but no clue how much to fix, how to keep it from turning into a mushy mess

Comment: Probably useful https://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/cooking-tips/article/make-ahead-pasta

Comment: It depends on how many entries are served, too. Beside military cook books, why don't you define a serving size and multiply it? Weight to volume usually has an impact in geometrically shaped items, like baking a pie or bread etc. But scaling tomato sauce or spaghetti should be easier, providing you have the necessary kitchenry.

Answer (score 1):

Well... sounds a little weird but you could search for military recipes. They usually have the ingredients amount for 100 people.

Comment: Maybe you could find something here https://www.marines.mil/Portals/59/Publications/MCO%20P10110.42B.pdf